# I am not good at formal logic, but I excel at moral philosophy and related branches. Does this mean that I cannot do philosophy?

Tags: ethics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does a philosopher need much knowledge of mathematical/formal logic?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/4167/does-a-philosopher-need-much-knowledge-of-mathematical-formal-logic)

That's right, I am weak in all subjects dealing with symbols and structures. My specialty lies with critical thinking. I found my talent useful in philosophy especially to moral philosophy. I am lucky that I have established my own ideas about meta-ethics. However I don't have fluency to this formal logic. But even so, can I still do philosophy?

Comment: See also http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/3846/can-a-philosopher-philosophize-without-logic

Comment: Symbols and structures help keep you honest.  Self-deception is easy, as is forgetting corner cases.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, the way one "does" philosophy is in an academic setting, so this question can only be answered by the department of philosophy of the school you attend or wish to attend.

That being said, I'm not sure what it means to specialize in "critical thinking" if one is "weak in all subjects dealing with symbols and structures."